# Adding mysql.data reference to VS2010

Tags: c#, sql, reference

[image: code]

"Before compiling the example code make sure that you have added References to your project as required. The References required are System, System.Data and MySql.Data."

How can i add references to the project ? I have already installed Connector/Net driver but where are the references stored and how can i import them to the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the project name.  Go to "Add Reference"... Locate the mysql assembly and select it.